# Recording audio on iPhone: error with setPreferredIOBufferDuration

Tags: iphone, audio, recording

I have been following Apple's documentation to record audio on the iPhone using the `AVAudioSession` class.  I can set several properties without error (`setActive`, `setCategory`, `setPreferredHardwareSampleRate`) but I cannot get Apple's sample code to work for `setPreferredIOBufferDuration`.

Here's my code:

```
- (void) initX {
 NSError *setPreferenceError = nil;
 NSTimeInterval preferredBufferDuration = 0.005;

 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
  setPreferredIOBufferDuration: preferredBufferDuration
  error: &setPreferenceError];

 if (setPreferenceError != nil) {
  NSLog( @"%@", setPreferenceError );
 }
}
```

It produces the following output:

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561211770 "Operation could not be completed. (OSStatus error 561211770.)"

I am calling this method from the main Application Delegate, as part of the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.  All I am doing is initializing things at this stage.  I have imported  AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h after adding AVFoundation.framework to the project.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a bug in Apple's code; use the pure C interface instead:

```
OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
Float32 preferredBufferDuration = 0.005;
propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration, sizeof(preferredBufferDuration), &preferredBufferDuration);
```

Then to check for errors use

```
if (propertySetError) NSLog(@"Failed to set shorter I/O buffer on AVAudioSession, code %d", propertySetError);
```

Comment: among other things, the Objective-C method takes an NSTimeInterval, which is a double, whereas the C method take a Float32, which is a float. Probably the reason for the "wrong size" error that the Obj-C method returns.